# How to create/register super user in django rest framework using apiview and token authentication

Tags: post, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to register super user from my application using post request by providing token.

I was trying create super user by simply calling a simple Url.

Answer (score 0):

I done this by using ApiView and Token Authentication you can follow these steps.
Step #1:
In your project level setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

Step#2: in your app level serializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['email','password','username']
```

Step #3:in your app level views.py

```
from api.serializer import RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token



class Register(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def post(self,request):
        Postserializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not (Postserializer.is_valid()):
            return response.Http404
        else:
            Postserializer.save()
            user = User.objects.get(Postserializer.data['username'])
            tokenobj ,_ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return {"Token":str(Postserializer['token'])}
```

Step #4 : in your app level url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/register/',Register.as_view())
]
```

Last Step : in your project level url.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/',include('api.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```